# Android drawing white color on canvas at start

Tags: java, android, xml, canvas

I want to draw red circles on white canvas, but it is black and becomes white only after first touch, so I want it to be white at beginning. Here is my code.
(also I want to know why the floating button doesn't show up :D)

DrawingView.java:

```
class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private ArrayList<Point> points;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    points = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    points.add(new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
    Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    for (Point p : points)
        canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 50, paint);
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    return false;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Save")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_save)
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    // do some magic to save :D
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .setShowAsAction(
                    MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                            | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="#DA4336"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="#E75043"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
    fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
    fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
    fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
    fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
    fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
    fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
    fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/insertPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_photo_24dp"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="Add photos" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addCircle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_1_24dp"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="Add circles" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

<reminder.com.paint.DrawingView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this DrawingView class

```
public class DrawView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {
private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
private Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Point point : points) {
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, point.radius, point.paint);
    }
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = event.getX();
    point.y = event.getY();
    point.radius = 30;
    int c = DrawingPage.selectedColorRGB;
    point.paint = new Paint();
    point.paint.setColor(c);
    points.add(point);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}}
```

And in main activity

```
drawView = new DrawView(getApplicationContext());
drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
drawView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: This worked for me and my floating buttons appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to that is using on create and there initializing the color to be white in DrawingView.java

```
public onCreate(...)
{
...

Set Color to white
...
}
```

**Heres an Edit:**
A real solution: 
in the constructor use the setBackground function and set it to white

```
ClassName(...)
{
Setbackground("WHITE")
}
```

Comment: You asked to know how to make the Surface white at the beginning so just use the one create and use the same function you use in the on touch method: Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: The DrawingView doesn't have a onCreate method

Comment: Look at my new suggestion

Comment: Now it's white but I can't draw on it.

Comment: I just added Setbackground("TRANSPARENT") in onTouchEvent and it worked!

Comment: Im really glad to help:)